# How to print an href/URL using XPath?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

My code navigates to a website, and in the website there is an article which contains its own link/url/href.

I want to print this field.

My current code highlights the container that it is in, and then I try to do a for loop to get the href.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import time

url = 'https://library.ehaweb.org/eha/#!*menu=6*browseby=8*sortby=2*media=3*ce_id=2035*label=21986*ot_id=25553*marker=1283*featured=17286'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page_source = driver.page_source

container=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='list-box col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 test']")
for j in container:
    link= j.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```

Comment: What is the name of this article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, you just need to print element's child (**a**) attribute:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='list-box col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 test']/a").get_attribute("href")
print(link)
```

This prints:

https://library.ehaweb.org/eha/2021/eha2021-virtual-congress/324511/hanny.al-samkari.pazopanib.for.severe.bleeding.and.transfusion-dependent.html?f=menu%3D6%2Abrowseby%3D8%2Asortby%3D2%2Amedia%3D3%2Ace_id%3D2035%2Alabel%3D21986%2Aot_id%3D25553%2Amarker%3D1283%2Afeatured%3D17286

If you want to use loop, then change `container=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='list-box col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 test']")` to

`container=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='list-box col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 test']")`

For exactly this element the following locator would be enough:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'test')]/a
```

With the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
url = 'https://library.ehaweb.org/eha/#!*menu=6*browseby=8*sortby=2*media=3*ce_id=2035*label=21986*ot_id=25553*marker=1283*featured=17286'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'test')]")
for j in container:
    link = j.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
driver.close()
```

Comment: can you please post the output of the for loop? im not sure if you used xpath for the //div[contains(@class, 'test')]/a line

Comment: https://library.ehaweb.org/eha/2021/eha2021-virtual-congress/324511/hanny.al-samkari.pazopanib.for.severe.bleeding.and.transfusion-dependent.html?f=menu%3D6%2Abrowseby%3D8%2Asortby%3D2%2Amedia%3D3%2Ace_id%3D2035%2Alabel%3D21986%2Aot_id%3D25553%2Amarker%3D1283%2Afeatured%3D17286

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in getting the href

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Loop through the list, take each element and fetch the required attribute value you want from it (in this case href).

Comment: How does that help?  The OP doesn't want the current URL, he wants the URL of an article contained within the website

Comment: Initial answer was completely different. Now it just slightly modified version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That page contain lots of inner URL. To click on EHA 2021 virtual container, you can use the below code.

```
eha_2021 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#listing-main a')
eha_2021_link = eha_2021_link.get_attribute('href')
print(eha_2021_link)
```

Just in case if you want to click on `COVID-19 Outbreak` you may try the below code.

**Code :**

```
covid_19_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'menu-8')
covid_19_url = covid_19_element.get_attribute('href')
print(covid_19_url)
```

**Suggestion :**

Try to avoid this kind of xpath `//div[@class='list-box col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 test']` this looks bit dynamic and may change region wise. Always use locater in below order :

1. ID
2. Name
3. TagName
4. Class Name
5. Link Text
6. Partial Link Text
7. CSS selector
8. XPATH

Learn about them [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)